# Typescript don't compile e.currentTarget.files

Tags: jquery, compiler-errors, typescript

I read with Jquery the files in a input

```
<INPUT TYPE=FILE id="file" NAME="upfile" multiple>
```

With this code

```
$('#inputFile').on('change', 'body', (e) => {
  var files: any = e.currentTarget.files;  });
```

But typescript don't know that e.currentTarget has the poperty files in this case. And give me a compile error.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#input-container').on('change', null, (e) => {
    var input = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
    var files = input.files; //give you intellisense on files
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.On` has different two overloads(version 1.8). You are using the wrong overloaded method. Use the correct one

If you don't have any data to be passed, change your code to

```
$('#inputFile').on('change', 'body', null, (e) => {
var files: any = e.currentTarget.files;  });
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, which is how to avoid the typescript compiler error for `e.currentTarget.files'

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @michael-tranchida but I think a bit cleaner:

```
export class Page {
    public fileToUpload:File = null;

    constructor(public fileInput: JQuery, public fileDetails: JQuery) {
        $(fileInput).on('change', (e) => {
            this.fileToUpload = <File>$(e.target).prop('files')[0];
            $(fileDetails).html(this.fileToUpload.name); // intellisense on fileToUpload
        });
    }
}
```